# I want to set the href of first li of the ul to "#1"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li class="nav-item"><a>Item #1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#2">Item #2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#3">Item #3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#4">Item #4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#5">Item #5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#6">Item #6</a></li>
</ul>
```

I had tried to something like below :-

```
$( 'ul[class="nav-list"] li:nth-child(1)' ).attr( "href", "#1" );
```

It not working because of there are other `ul` tags also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<li>` elements don't have `href` attributes, that belongs in the `<a>` element. So it should be:

```js
$('ul[class="nav-list"] li:nth-child(1) a').attr("href", "#1");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li class="nav-item"><a>Item #1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#2">Item #2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#3">Item #3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#4">Item #4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#5">Item #5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#6">Item #6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this

First Method

```
$('ul.nav-list li a:nth-child(1)' ).attr( "href", "#1" );
```

Second method

```
$('ul.nav-list li a').eq(0).attr( "href", "#1" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this:

```
$( 'ul li a:first-child' ).attr( "href", "#1" );
OR
$('ul[class="nav-list"] li:nth-child(1) a').attr("href", "#1");
```

Comment: $( 'ul.nav-list li.nav-item a:first-child' ).attr( "href", "#1" );